# Checking inherited visibility of DOM element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have the HTML below:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <span id="hello">Hey</span>
</div>
```

And I do `alert($("#hello").css("display"));`, it will say "inline". The span is clearly not visible, but since it doesn't directly have a `display:none;` property on it, it still says it's viewable.

How do I test whether a certain DOM element is actually visible or not, even if its parent or a parent of its parent is not displaying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
if ($('#myitem').is(':visible')){

/*Do some sort of stuff in here */

}
```

Items still animating (like using `.hide` or `.fadeOut`) will be "visible" until the animation is complete

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector, and the [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```
if($("#hello").is(":visible")) {
    //It's visible!
}
```

The `is` method returns a boolean value indicating whether or not *any* of the matched elements match that selector.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(selector).is(':visible')`

Answer (score 0):

use the [.is() function](http://api.jquery.com/is/) along with the [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) or [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) psuedoselectors:

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/ucSVx/

```
$('#hello').is(':hidden')
```